загрузка фото через телеграмм имеет ли смысл делать отдельную кнопку
Интересует такой вопрос.делаю бота на питоне,есть кнопка загрузить квитанцию. Но "скрепка" по умолчанию телеграмма присутствует всегда. Есть ли смысл в моей кнопке если пользователь и так в любое время может загрузить квитанции.

ИМХО, про "скрепку" мало кто помнит. А вот если будет отдельная кнопка, то это выйдет нагляднее и в дальнейшем проще добавлять типы аттачей.
